# Disable wrap/increase width buffer

Tags: conemu, buffer

I have looked at the settings and the [ConEmu project wiki](http://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/wiki/TableOfContents?tm=6) but I am not able to find how to turn off wrapping or increase the width buffer so that the text written on the console appears on one single line.

When I try to change the buffer under the Size&Pos. it affects the actual window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ATM there is no full support of horizontal scrolling, this is in "RoadMap". However, some applications (like `wmic.exe` for example) are able to set large buffer itself, but there is ho horizontal scrolling in ConEmu in the current version.

Comment: Hi, has this changed since? Thanks.

Comment: this is a big let down for me.